# Linking from 1 page to another via a Start Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I created a game using JS/CSS/HTML5, just something simple, however, I have used a start button.. with the following code:

```
$('#StartBtn').click(LaunchGame);
```

Which when pressed launches the game from the home screen.. however when the player loses on the game, the game panel disappears and the words "busted, Try Again" appear, which is fine, however, I'm trying to get the Start Button to appear after 2/3secs linking back through to the home page to restart the game.. However, I just can't figure out how to do it.

Below is the code that appears when the game ends..

```
function EndGame(HasTiledOut) {
    ShowHomeScreen();

    $('#EntireScreen').html('');

    var GameOutcomeText = (HasTiledOut) ? 'Busted!!' : 'Try Again!';

    $('#GameOutcome').text(GameOutcomeText).fadeIn();
}
```

If more code is needed, I'd be happy to provide it if its makes it easier on answering

Comment: What does your HTML markup look like?

Comment: What does ShowHomeScreen() do? Is '#EntireScreen' the element containing all others? If so, $('#EntireScreen').html(''); removes all html after the showhomescreen function. Is that ok?

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3z88zp9d/150/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to delay a event, like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ [your code here] }, 3000);
```

Remember that it uses milliseconds so the 3000 is 3 seconds.

Comment: @carlosherrera -- showHomeScreen(); does just that when the game ends, it reshows the entire homescreen, which isn't that bad.. but i'd like for the StartButton to appear to link back through to the homescreen -- giving the player the option to carry on..

Answer (score 0):

As the game starts hide the start button and let the event attached to it. just hide it..

```
$('#StartBtn').hide();
```

In the end game in EndGame() method again show the button

```
 `setTimeout(function() {
  $('#StartBtn').show();
  }, 5000);`
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64465/discussion-between-midae-and-ninja).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this when game starts

```
$('#StartBtn').click(function(){
LaunchGame();
$('#StartBtn').hide();
});
```

and when game is end

```
$('#GameOutcome').text(GameOutcomeText).fadeIn(300, function() {$('#StartBtn').show()});
```

When fadeIn effect is ended the StartButton appear.